Resend invites to a Google Calendar regular event
I have a bi-weekly regular event in Google for Workspaces Calendar. The event has started 1 year ago. Some recipients declined the event and cannot find the old invite email.
How can I resend the invite (with RSVP buttons) to the regular event to everyone or to these specific recipients?
I cannot remove-and-readd these recipients because they are added to the event as a Google Group and not individually. Using the "email guests" button also serves to nothing because the sent emails do not contain the *.ics file or a way to Yes to the this regular event.

Add them individually to the event.

Google Calendar does not allow to re-add (or remove) an individual user who is a member of a Google Group which itself is added to the event :(

Thanks for the response. Please [edit] your question to include that information as well as the way it fails (eg. how did you add them, what was the error message, etc.).

This already is somewhat included in the question: I cannot remove-and-readd these recipients because they are added to the event as a Google Group and not individually. . "Adding individually" does not work for the same reason as "re-adding individually" not working... And there is no error message, just the button adding is gray and not available for clicking... But I'll add this info in the question for more clarity

I'm still a bit confused if you try to add another unrelated user then the button is active but it can tell it's the specific users and it remains grayed out? Also be useful to understand what you mean by "Group" as it has a few different interpretations in the Google ecosystem. Also do you have "View members"  permissions for the group or not.

I'm the admin of the workspace, so yes, I have "View members" (and indeed the participant in question is member of the group which is already added to the event by itself). Yes, I can add another unrelated user to the event, but I can't add the user (e.g. "myuser@mydomain.org") which is already included into the group (e.g. "mygroup@mydomain.org") which is added into the event participants by itself.

I'm not trying to be a pain, but again this is all relevant details that should be added in the question, if someone wants to try to replicate the problem and/or narrow down the potential issues. What is the group/how was it created/what are the group settings?

Has your user(s) tried enabling "Show declined events" in their calendar settings then changing their status? Have you tried sending them an ics attachment via email?

Thanks for the tip "Show declined events", I'll check this. For ics, I was not very content about the hack of creating a calendar and duplicating an event into it to get the individual event's ics file. Is there another way?

From one of the original invite emails download the ICS file. If necessary edit it for the affected group member (if the files aren't identical for all members) then email it to the affected Gmail group member. If you can't find an original invitation with ICS then create a new one by adding a new temporary guest to the event, then edit the ICS file they receive by email with the group or group member's info before removing the temporary participant and sending the ICS file to the affected group member.

About the group: nothing special, all default settings. And it works well together with invites except that one cannot remove/add/re-add group participants from the invite if the group itself is added as participant...
